# Can I pass a component as an attribute in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm building a generic lookup component in lightning. I'd like to be able to pass custom templates into this component. Can this be done as an attribute?

Here's the relevant component and what I tried now.

```
<aura:component controller="lightningUtils">
<aura:attribute type="List" name="filteredResults" />
<aura:attribute type="String" name="template" default="templateLookupDefault"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>


<div class="slds-form-element">
    <ui:inputText aura:id="quickLookupInput" class="slds-input" value="{!v.search}" updateOn="keyup" keyup="{!c.filterList}" placeholder="Search" />
</div>

<c:{!v.template} filteredResults="{!v.filteredResults}"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to reference a component dynamically? If that's the case, you could create a component and insert it into the markup through your controller. Here's an example:

```
// markup
<div aura:id='divToSet'>

</div>

// controller
$A.createComponent('c:COMPONENT_NAME_HERE',
    {
        'filteredResults': someValueHere
    },
    function(newComp){
        component.find('divToSet').set('v.body', newComp);
    }
);
```

I have not hit any snags using this method in the past. Hope this helps!